# Material-UI lagging text when open menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[Issue Video](https://store1.gofile.io/download/b04c8496-767e-4bfc-ae5b-91640d3d2e92/135114103-2bba4420-cfa5-41fe-96ae-892618ffb09c%20(1).mov)

I have a problem when open and close the `Menu`. Follow the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yr193?file=/demo.tsx).
I don't know why the text just change the position slowly. Please help me.

This is my devDependencies I using config webpack.

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.21",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.45.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-date-range": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^8.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.33.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [`TransitionProp`](https://mui.com/api/menu/#:%7E:text=%2C%20or%20%27auto%27-,TransitionProps,-object) to change the duration of the opening animation. See the full prop list of the `Transition` component [here](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition):

```
<Menu
  TransitionProps={{
    timeout: 0
  }}
  {...}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: thank for your's answer. But when i using timeout: 0, Menu have no animation when open popup.

Comment: @steven_phan can you clarify your goal? I thought you want to reduce the transition time.

Comment: As you can see in my video. The Text in Menu Item is lagging. I transfer code to new project create-react-app but it's the same. 
But in the sample Menu create by mui.com. It's work perfect. I don't know the difference. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/yr193?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @steven_phan I can see it now, sorry I misread your question. Can you add [`CssBaseline`](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/#main-content) component to your app and see if it still happens?

Comment: thank @nearhuscarl but it's doesn't work. 
You can check in this repo: https://github.com/totoro0103/Menu-Item-Issue
If you run this project in localhost. It still happens. But if I deploy to Vercel. It's work perfect. Magic !!!. It's very very confuse.@@
https://menu-item-issue-hcpzoecd4-totoro0103.vercel.app/